# How do I predict the location of the next cell? (Writing the Grand Total)

Tags: c#, vba, excel, epplus

You know how when you're copying cells in excel from one cell to the next and the formula automatically replaces something like `=Sum(A1+$B1)` to `=Sum(C1+$B1)`?

I was wondering how to achieve something similar, except programmatically done.

This is what I'm trying to achieve, I have a table with say, a place's revenue for rows and the item for the columns, this is pre-pivoted data in case you were wondering, and I want to complete it with a grand total, which is initially missing.

```
Place     | Beans | Buns | Breads | etc
Bobby's   |   550 |   20 |     30 |  10
Sen's     |   550 |   20 |     30 |  10
Solaire's |   550 |   20 |     30 |  10
```

Now, I'm going to be writing one extra row below the last one, and one extra column beside the last one, titled [Grand Total].

So, I'm guessing I am going to be needing a for loop to run through that last row I'm going to generate. Something like this:

```
For (int i = 2; i < numberofColumns; i++) {
    string query = "=Sum(? : ?)"
    xlsWorksheet.Cells[ numberofRows + 1 , i].Formula = query;
}
```

As you can see, I'm not sure how to handle the implicit cell locations. The tricky part is that I want this algorithm to loop to the end without having to implicitly define a specific cell. This is because I can have any number of extra columns, or any number of extra rows in between. The important part is that I would need to create the Grand total row and column.

A desired outcome would be:

```
Place     | Beans | Buns | Breads | etc | GrandTotal
Bobby's   |   550 |   20 |     30 |  10 |        610
Sen's     |   550 |   20 |     30 |  10 |        610
Solaire's |   550 |   20 |     30 |  10 |        610
          |  1650 |   60 |     90 |  30 |       1830
```

At the moment, this is being done in C# targeting an Excel document with Excel Interop. I understand that this can also be done in VBA or Excel formulas, so I'm going to tag both of those to this post. The formula itself will be doing more than simply summing the rows, but I just cannot figure out how to predict the location of the following cell.

Comment: The exact same way you'd do it in VBA: by tracking where you started and what the last row & column with data is. BTW `query` is a terrible name for a string containing a `SUM` formula, *especially* in C# where `query` is a name that's commonly used for an `IQueryable<T>` object.

Comment: If you're not writing the data yourself, then you need to "find the last row/column in a range", and that's a solved problem you can easily find a solution for.

Comment: Lastly, if your data is "pre-pivoted", then why isn't it in a pivot table, which can quite easily calculate these totals for you? Exactly what does "will be doing more than simply summing the rows" mean? Your examples (including the `"=Sum(? : ?)"` part) all imply a straight-up sum.

Comment: This function is part of a much larger project that involves reading an excel file, of which a pattern is already defined, created and unmanaged. In other words, these pivot-ed tables are fed to my C# program as is, and the program churns out the optimal arrangement of the document, in other words, I'm trying to optimize having to change 1000 pivoted tables and placing grand totals (program does more than just that) in each of them. It would be easier if everything was complete by the time it reached the program but that is not the case. @Mat'sMug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an option, I'm sure it's not the most efficient though:

```
lCol = Sheets("SheetName").Cells(1, Sheets("SheetName").Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
lRow = Sheets("SheetName").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Sheets("SheetName").Cells(1, lCol + 1).Value = "Grand Total"

For i = 2 To lRow

    Sheets("SheetName").Cells(i, lCol + 1).Formula = "=SUM(RC[-" & lCol - 1 & "]:RC[-1])"

Next i

lCol = Sheets("SheetName").Cells(1, Sheets("SheetName").Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For i = 2 To lCol

    Sheets("SheetName").Cells(lRow + 1, i).Formula = "=SUM(R[-" & lRow - 1 & "]C:R[-1]C)"

Next i
```

Comment: I should be able to convert this into C# syntax and test it. I forgot about R1C1 for cell naming, I was stuck on writing a dictionary for cell letters.

Comment: Thanks, R1C1 notation is exactly what I needed.